# does anyone know how to fix the protection level on C drive when Debugging

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

This is the message that keeps popping up everytime I debug. I try to fix the outpath but its just not doing anything. Where does the outpath need to be set to?

[image]

Comment: There is a picture there but its not showing up. The message is saying please rebuild project and retry, or set the outpath and assemblyname properties appropriately to point at the current location at the target assembly

Comment: `....MyCheckBox.exe\MyCheckBox.exe` doesnt seem right